# Issue applying HTML font-family with a space within C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

I am having what appears to be a simple issue with getting my font-family to take when trying to write it in my C# code behind my aspx page in Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web.  I have code using HtmlTextWriter so I can click a button on the page and print my gridview. When trying to apply some HTML formatting to the "Title" of the page, the font-family will not change.  This has only been an issue when assigning a font-family that has a 'space' in the name.

```
string title = "<b><center><p style=font-size:32px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'>" + Title1.Text + "<p/><center/><b/>";
```

I have tried various ways that I have found in other cases.  This way works if I am just in the C# code behind the page, but it does not work in the same code behind if I am doing in my HtmlTextWriter section.

```
"<b><center><p style=\"font-size:24px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'\">" + Title1.Text + "<p/><center/><b/>";
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
protected void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;

    GridView1.DataBind();

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    sw.Write("<style type=\"text/css\">.gridView caption {color: black;font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;}</style>");

    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")

        .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");

    string title = "<center><p style=\"font-size:32px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'\"><b>" + Title1.Text + "<b/><p/><center/>";  //This formats the title above the gridview when printing     

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");

    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");

    sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");

    sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");

    sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");

    sb.Append(title);  //This displays the title above the gridview

    sb.Append(gridHTML);  //This displays the gridview

    sb.Append("\");");

    sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");

    sb.Append("printWin.focus();");

    sb.Append("printWin.print();");

    sb.Append("printWin.close();};");

    sb.Append("</script>");

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());

    GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = true;

    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have for your HtmlTextWriter

Comment: Creating html mark up with StringBuilder from code behind is not a commanded approach, as it is very fragile. How you use that ***title*** variable? Could you show the code of ***HtmlTextWriter***?

Comment: @Win is right, you'll need at least to HTML-encode that title before storing it

Comment: Thank you all.  I have added the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not well-formed, and you're using invalid closing tags.

Also, if you don't add the `\"` like you're doing in the second code line, your browser will treat the space in the font family as a separation between html attributes.

This is the way you should do it:

```
"<center><p style=\"font-size:24px;font-family:'Palatino Linotype'\"><b>" + Title1.Text + "</b></p></center>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I.G.  That is the direction that I was heading.  So, the issue that I was/am seeing when adjusting to your suggestion above, is now when I click the button to invoke the HtmlTextWriter portion of the code, it will not work.  The popup window will not come up and the print dialog will not come up either of course.

Comment: @Zwick44 You're making us trying to resolve something completely blinded there are more a thousand of possibilities. Give us your code, a working example.. work on it a little to give us something more detailed. __Create a Complete, Minimal, Verificable example__ http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Understood.  I added the HtmlTextWriter code with your suggestion added to my original post.  Thanks again.

Comment: What does your script console print? Does it throw any error?

Comment: This is what I am getting in the debug output window when I click the Print button:  Critical error was detected at line 128, column 190 in http://localhost:61730/Home.aspx.
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
The thread 0x1b6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: That means that the javascript you're creating in your StringBuilder is incorrect. Inspect the html code you're delivering to the browser, find the JavaScript code and look for those JavaScript errors

Comment: Thanks I.G.  I do follow you.  So, this is the behavior that I see.  1. If I comment out the "sb.Append(title);", the print function will work, but of course without the "title".  If I change my title formatting to say,"<center><p style=font-size:36px;font-family:Arial><b>"... it will work and apply the Arial font family.  It still appears the issue arises when I add the \" that I need to appropriately handle the white space in the  Palatino Linotype font family name.